# Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 7/5 & 1/5\\ -1 & 1/2\\\end{pmatrix}. $$

Determine $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A^{n} $

Is the limit related to the eigenvalues? Using Matlab it appears that the matrix does not have a limit as n is increased.

Comment: Yes, it is. Find the Jordan form of $A$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can diagonalize the matrix: $A=PDP^{-1}$
where
$$D=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 9/10\\\end{pmatrix} \qquad P = \begin{pmatrix} -1/2 & 1/5\\ -2/5 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence
$$A^{n}=\left(PDP^{-1}\right)^{n}=PD^{n}P^{-1}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}A^{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}PD^{n}P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} -1/2 & 1/5\\ -2/5 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -10 & -4\\ 10 & 5\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 2\\ -10 & -4\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** if
$$
A =P
\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b\\
   d & e    \end{pmatrix}
P^{-1}
$$
then
$$
A^n=P
\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b\\
   d & e    \end{pmatrix}^n
P^{-1}
$$

Hence, you shoud start with the reduction of the matrix, to make the middle part as easy to handle as possible (for instance, it is possible to make $b=0$).

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial for $A$ is

$$\chi_A(\lambda) = \det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda - \frac75 & -\frac15 \\ 1 & \lambda - \frac12\end{bmatrix} = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda - \frac{9}{10})$$

By [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), we have
$$(A - I )(A - \frac{9}{10} I) = 0$$

This implies

$$
\begin{cases}
A ( A - \frac{9}{10} I ) &= ( A - \frac{9}{10}I ) \\
A ( A - I ) &= \frac{9}{10} (A - I)
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
A^n ( A - \frac{9}{10} I ) &= ( A - \frac{9}{10}I ) \\
A^n ( A - I ) &= \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^n (A - I)
\end{cases}
\text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
As a result,

$$A^n = 10 A^n \left(( A - \frac{9}{10}I) - ( A - I)\right)
      = 10 \left( ( A - \frac{9}{10} I ) - \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^n (A - I) \right)\\
\implies
\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n = 10 A - 9 I = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 2\\ -10 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice answer, (+1). By the way, I've been in vain trying to contact you. I was wondering if I could acknowledge you (for suggesting the use of Mertens' third theorem and providing a proof of it) in my paper on Robin's inequality.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Please don't acknowledge me. I just find interesting questions on math.SE to burn my time. No strings attached.

Comment: I see, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-2/5&-1/5\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.9&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}10&5\\-10&-4\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Just regarding your Matlab comment,

```
A=[7/5,1/5;-1,1/2];
disp(A);
B= A*A*A*A*A;
D=B*B*B*B;
C=D*D*D*D*D;
disp(C*C*C*C);
```

gives

```
   1.40000   0.20000
  -1.00000   0.50000

    5.0000    2.0000
  -10.0000   -4.0000
```

so possibly you need to try harder there.

Comment: Or just `A^100`. (A lot less typing than repeated multiplication.)